# Liu, Algebraic Geometry, Corollary 9.3.30 ( $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{T,\xi} \to T$ is smooth? )

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading proof of Corollary 9.3.30 in the Liu's Algebraic geometry and Arithmetic curves and stuck at some point.

> Corollary 9.3.30. Let $\pi : X\to S$ be an arithmetic surface ( ; i.e., a regular surface over a Dedekind scheme of dimension $1$) such that $p_a(X_{\eta})=1$. Let $f : T\to S$ be a smooth morphism. Then for any point $\xi \in T$ of codimension $1$, $X\times_S \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{T,\xi}$ is a minimal arithmetic surface over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{T,\xi}$.

**Q.1.** What is the definition of codimension of point? There is a definition of codimension of closed subset ( his book p.69 ). Here, he implicitly assume that $\xi$ is closed point?

**Proof** Let us first note that $X\times_S T$ is smooth over $X$, and hence regular ( Theorem 4.3.36 ). **Therefore $X\times_S \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{T,\xi}$ is regular.** (Next proof is omitted..)

Here, the Theorem 4.3.36 is,

> Theorem 4.3.36. Let $Y$ be a regular locally Noetherian scheme, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a smooth morphism. Then $X$ is regular.

**Q.2.** Why the bold statement is true? If the canonical map $j_{\xi} : \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{T,\xi} \to T$ is smooth, then $X\times_S \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{T,\xi} \cong (X \times_S T)\times_T \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{T,\xi}$ is smooth over $X\times_S T$. So by again the Theorem 4.3.36, $X\times_S \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{T,\xi}$ is regular.

But $j_{\xi} : \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{T,\xi} \to T$ is not necessarily smooth? If $\xi$ is of codimension $1$, is that true? Or is there any other route to show the regularity?  Can anyone help?

Comment: As for Q1, the codimension of a point $\xi$ is usually defined to be the codimension of the closure $\overline{\{\xi\}}$, or equivalently the dimension of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X, \xi}$.

Comment: As for Q2, are you wondering how to get the bold statement from the theorem, or just how to prove the bold statement from the preceding steps? I agree that it's not clear how to use the theorem to go from $X \times_S T$ being regular to $X \times_S \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{T, \xi}$ being regular.

Comment: Yes. If we try to prove the bold statement from the preceding steps, how can we approach ?~

Comment: For the proof of the bold statement, one may assume that $X$, $T$ and $S$ are affine. So suppose that $A$ and $B$ are smooth $R$-algebras, where $R$ is a Dedekind ring (actually noetherian and regular is enough). Let $S\subset B$ be a multiplicative set and let $T\subseteq A\otimes_R B$ be the mult. set of elements $1\otimes s$, where $s\in S$. Then we have an iso of rings $$(A\otimes_R B)[T^{-1}]\simeq A\otimes_R B[S^{-1}]$$ by Ex. 1.2.2 in Liu's book and by  Th. 4.4 in Matsumura, Commutative Algebra. Since $A\otimes_R B$ is regular, so is $(A\otimes_R B)[T^{-1}]$.

Comment: ... applying this to the case where $S$ is the complement of a prime ideal, you get what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I almost got it! Can I ask more? I am checking that we may assume $X$, $T$, $S$ are affines. Q.1. Why can we assume that $S=\operatorname{Spec}R$ is affine?

Comment: Q.2. And let  $p_1 : X \times_S \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}B,\xi} \to X$ be the projection. For $\bar{x} \in X\times_S \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}B,\xi }$ with $ p_1(\bar{x}) \in \operatorname{Spec}A$ ( affine open neighborhood ), $\bar{x} \in \operatorname{Spec}A \times_{\operatorname{Spec}R}\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}B,\xi}) = \operatorname{Spec}(A \otimes_R \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}B,\xi})$ ?